# Analytic solution for AC current density in a wire? (skin effect)

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity

As I was reading about skin effect , I realized that the skin depth $\delta$ is defined assuming a plane wave incidence with a flat media and then the surface current is given by:
$$J=J_se^{-{\delta}/{z}}$$
I think the method is not applicable to a wire, specially at low frequencies were the current can not be considered as *surface current* anymore. I'm looking for an analytic solution for the ac current density in a cylindrical wire carrying a total sinusoidal current $I$ with frequency $f$.

[image]

Comment: I think $J_s$ is DEFINED as the current density at the surface. I don't know what you mean by "the current can not be CONSIDERED as surface current anymore"

Comment: @KeithMcClary If the current density in cylindrical wire should have a function like $e^{-{\delta}/{r}}$, in high frequencies it is negligible at the center however at lower frequencies it is not negligible anymore.

Comment: @KeithMcClary Also in finding the relation of $J=J_se^{-{\delta}/{z}}$ it is assumed that there exists a plain surface not a wire. I think in high frequencies since $\lambda$ is very small, the surface of wire can be considered as plain.

Comment: When they write textbooks they like to describe examples where there is a nice analytic solution. They don't often tell you "this is the only explicit solution we know". [This paper mentions an exact solution in terms of Bessel functions](http://www.df.unipi.it/~macchi/TEACHING/FISICA2/PROBLEMS/skineffect.pdf) but it is not clear to me whether they are only solving an approximate equation.

Comment: @KeithMcClary Thank you for this nice paper. I think it is assumed that $\frac{\partial E}{\partial t}$ is negligible in $\nabla\times B=\mu_0 J+\mu_0\epsilon_0\frac{\partial E}{\partial t}$ and by this approximation Bessel function is the answer.